# Map characters with correspondent name

Tags: python, pandas, string-matching

I have the following dataframe:

```
strings.   intention
g          google
go         google
yo         youtube
y          youtube
a          amazon
am         amazon
skys       skype
```

What I would like to do is to map the characters with the strings, so if I have in the first-row "g" and the intention as google then it matches but, the last row is "skys" and the intention is skype,  the 4th character is not a match, then is false.

And the final result that I`m looking for is:

```
strings.   intention       match
    g          google      TRUE
    go         google      TRUE
    yo         youtube     TRUE
    y          youtube     TRUE
    a          amazon      TRUE
    am         amazon      TRUE
    skys       skype       FALSE
```

What I tried so far is this, it works but not completely as there are some examples where I have  the string "ne" and it is suppose to show netflix but it shows "nykaa" for example. Is there a better way to do this?

```
keywords = dict(zip(df.string, df['intent_pretty_name']))
df['match'] = [next((keywords[y] for y in x.split() if y in keywords), None) for x in df['strings']]
```

thanks

Comment: Could be pretty much done with a Trie, what are you using dataframes for?

Comment: I have also information regarding clicks and views in my dataframe so I want to know if the string that was typed matches with the intention and if not then how it reflects on the data (i.e. less clicks). I`m not familiar with Trie, can you clarify?

Comment: It's a data structure that helps you do prefix lookups in logn time. Creating the datastructure itself might take nlogn time though

Answer (score 0):

You can do the comparison with a simple `string.startswith`

```
#for corresponding string and intention
match = intention.startswith(string) #returns true or false
```

### References:

- [startswith](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/startswith.html)

Comment: I tried this solution and got NaN result for the entire columns. Any idea what could I`ve done wrong? 
string = df['string']
df['match'] = df['intention'].str.startswith(string)

Comment: What exactly is string? Try print debugging and check if you are matching the strings properly

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind `apply` (can be slow on big datasets) you can do `startswith` like this:

```
df['match'] = df.apply(lambda s: s['intention'].startswith(s['strings']),axis=1)
```

---

```
df
Out[139]: 
  strings intention  match
0       g    google   True
1      go    google   True
2      yo   youtube   True
3       y   youtube   True
4       a    amazon   True
5      am    amazon   True
6    skys     skype  False
```

Answer (score 0):

For vectorized solution you can leverage `pd.Series.replace(...)` with `regex=True`:

```py
df["match"] = df["intention"].replace(df["strings"]+".*", "True", regex=True).eq("True")
```

Outputs:

```py
  strings intention  match
0       g    google   True
1      go    google   True
2      yo   youtube   True
3       y   youtube   True
4       a    amazon   True
5      am    amazon   True
6    skys     skype  False
```